# Jquery toggle not working in php foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to show a booking form when I click the button using jquery toggle.

**HTML**

```
foreach($result['apiAvailableBuses'] as $value){?>
    <tr>
</td>
        <td><?php echo $value['fare']; ?></td>
        <td>

            <?php echo $value['availableSeats'].'&nbsp;Seats'; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="button" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" value="Book" name="Book">
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr class="main">
        <td colspan="5">
            <div class="well" id="result<?php echo $i; ?>">Booking form here</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php $i++; } ?>
```

**Script**

```
$(".main").hide();
$(".btn-primary").click(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
        $('#result'+id).toggle();
    });
```

But when I click on the button I can't see the booking form div

Comment: Its wrapped in ready function

Comment: You also have a closing `</td>` tag right after the opening `<tr>` tag ..

Comment: what is `$i`, it's not declared anywhere

Comment: @Disha i've declared it.

Comment: try passing $('#result'+id).toggle(true);

Answer (score 2):

In your script, you are hiding the parent `tr` using `$(".main").hide();` and hence `toggle` of the child element is not working. To make it work you have to make visible the parent element and then toggle the div.

```
$(".main").hide();
$(".btn-primary").click(function(){
       $(".main").show();
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    $('#result'+id).toggle();
});
```

Now it should work.

Comment: it displays all the divs

Comment: @Blessan, please modify the selector as per your requirement to select the correct tr element to show and not all tr element...

Comment: `$('#result'+id).closest('tr.main').toggle();` might work?

Comment: Again select all the divs

Comment: @BlessanKurien, remove `$(".main").show();` and replace `$('#result'+id).toggle();` with `$('#result'+id).closest('tr.main').toggle();`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.on()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on("click",".btn-primary",function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    $('#result'+id).toggle();
});
});
```

**UPDATE**

Another thing I want to explain.
You are clicking on a button and then getting its ID and then doing `.toggle()` with it.

I think you can do this way also.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on("click",".btn-primary",function(){
    //var id=$(this).attr('id');
    //$('#result'+id).toggle();
    $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").find(".well").toggle();
});
});
```

Comment: remove unwanted `</td>` from third line of your HTML code.

Comment: Nop ,actually  its only a small portion of the code a full HTML table is included

Comment: Yeah its wroked,but the inital load all the pages display

Comment: You can hide in on page load by adding `$(".main").hide();`

Comment: when `$(".main").hide()` using this the first proble is occures